# How to change the position of the same content inside the blocks

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm using react, so I have 4 simple blocks, left to right.

```
    <div className="box wrapper">
      <img alt="customAlt" src={image} />
      <p>{text} </p>
    </div>
```

The second block and the forth block, I want the position to change so that p tag come first before the image.

What is the best way to do this? I tried to use flexbox with nth child, but doesn't work:

```
.box wrapper:nth-child p(even){
    order: 1
}

.box wrapper:nth-child img(even){
    order: 2
}
```

I'm wondering if it's supposed to be done in css or there's proper way to do this in react? because I store all my data in other file, so I prefer not to duplicate the content.

Please advice, thanks.

Comment: it should be `.box wrapper:nth-child(even) p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS doesn't look quite right. You have two classes, 'box' and 'wrapper', so replace the space in between them with a dot. It may be useful to take a look at [this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for CSS selectors.

The '(even)' needs to come after nth-child. Try this instead:

```
.box.wrapper:nth-child(even) p {
   order: 1
}

.box.wrapper:nth-child(even) img {
   order: 2
}
```

To add clarification, .box.wrapper:nth-child(even) p is like saying, select each paragraph tag, within each evenly-indexed child of each element whose parent has the class, 'example'.

P.s. I didn't know about the order property for flexbox, despite using it all the time, so thanks!